# How can I comment on a proposed edit of one of my questions?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this proposed edit in my inbox:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7526479

It's pretty troubling that there are 3 approvals and only 1 reject:

[image: Insightful comment]

Now stan0 is a bit more generous than I am with this edit. It's just wrong. It changes my question from something that makes sense regarding a class which exists in Ember to gibberish about an imaginary class that does not exist in Ember.

This smells like someone trying to game StackOverflow to get reputation. Of course, if I had more reputation, I could comment on this edit and explain how terrible it is.

Comment: What do you want to say, and to whom?  Do you want to post a comment to the editor, the reviewer, a mod, or what?

Comment: I'd like to comment on the suggested edit to let the reviews know that the edit changes the class name from something that exists to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Those reviewers won't be doing so again for a little while. Getting pretty antsy for this to be implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits#comment821383_221832

Comment: +1 @BradLarson. Glad to see that people are trying to stem this trend.

Comment: That comment "*This edit does not make the post even a little better...*" is a canned remark. Stan0 didn't write that. It's one of the set of four-five standard reasons for rejecting edits.

Comment: @BradLarson the guy is still going at it. He's still wholesale adding UI and NS prefixes, even when this makes no sense at all (like when the user referred to the concept of a "navigation bar" and didn't want to turn that into UINavigationBar). He needs to be stopped.

Comment: @BradLarson OTOH you should hire this guy as a honeypot for robo-reviewers

Comment: The user in question has gained over 500 points in the past week through edits alone, and most of the ones I spot-checked were quick edits like this. (Though at least most of them were actually on iOS/XCode questions, unlike this case.)

Answer (score 10):

If you feel that the edit was invalid, you can use the rollback option to go back to a previous revision.

Once someone edits a post, they can be pinged in comments, so you can ask them directly what their reasoning was.

If you feel the editor may need to be more strongly dealt with, you can raise a custom flag on your own question explaining this.  A moderator can then investigate and take action if necessary.

---

Note that no moderators were involved in approving that edit.  You can distinguish moderators by the ♦ next to their name.  If you feel that any reviewers, regardless of rep, privilege, or moderator status, should be more closely examined, raise a flag explaining that.  Moderators *are* the ones who look at custom flags.

Comment: Personally, I think the moderators who approved the edit need to be "more strongly dealt with." Not really but it'd be nice if people took the time to understand an edit before approving it. I'd like to comment on the review because that's where I see a problem.

Comment: @spinlock No moderators approved the edit.  If you feel that the *users* (regardless of their status as moderator or any other privilege) should be examined, you should raise a flag explaining that.

Comment: @davidism I received my first notification from SO about Suggested Edits. Where is this "rollback option"? I don't see ANY options on the Suggested Edits page that I have access to. What options should I have? I could not find any SO docs on how the Suggested Edits process works. Could you steer me to some?